# Is it possible to choose all the empty grid areas

Tags: css-selectors, css-grid

Is it possible to use CSS selectors to select empty grid areas (which are usually written with a dot `.`)?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(4, 80px) / repeat(4, 80px);
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-areas: "a0 . a2 ." "b0 . b2 ." "c0 . c2 ." "d0 . d2 .";
}
```

Comment: No. Grid areas are not DOM elements and so cannot be targeted with CSS.

Comment: It's my understanding that empty grid areas are just for when you want nothing there, so there would be no reason to style them. If you want to style them maybe look into putting something in their place